# Sanity check of an Ubuntu system after a release upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Is there a way  to verify the sanity/consistency/integrity of an Ubuntu system after a release upgrade, particularly if the upgrade process did not go smoothly or did not follow standard/recommended procedure?

Comment: Open a terminal and check your release `lsb_release -a` , then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` . Post any errors you get. Beyond that what sort of sanity check do you envision ?

Comment: @Panther I would primarily imagine checks on implicit consistency constraints on the configuration in /etc, particularly /etc/apt. I do not know what those might be, but a recursive grep show that some files in there still mention zesty. I get no errors for the commands you suggest and the systems thinks it is 17.10 artful.

Comment: Try the standard upgrade options

Answer (score 0):

> particularly if the upgrade process did not go smoothly

Either the upgrade is completed correctly or it will stop with a notice. So no, there is no post upgrade sanity check except for the normal error notice that the upgrade failed.

If you can update your system after the upgrade all can be considered well.

> did not follow standard/recommended procedure?

There is no "not follow standard/recommended procedure?".

The method to upgrade from an officially released version to the next officially released version in `do-release-upgrade` (or if you do it prior to the official release of the new version it is `do-release-upgrade -d`).

Comment: What if the `do-relase-update` command was interrupted? Do you rerun from the start? is it idempotent? How do you avoid having a franken install that pulls some packages from old repos and some from new ones?

Comment: "How do you avoid having a franken install that pulls some packages from old repos and some from new ones?" Ehm impossible. The system will refuse to pull in packages from 2 different versions. That is the "broken dependency" error notice you might have seen before. Fixing that error alway includes updating to the newer version. I always do a reinstall en add my personal partition since that is  a lot  quicker (takes 16m to do a full reinstall. 4m more to install the software I use that is not in the base install ;) )

Comment: What is your procedure for that. I currently have a bunch of files in /etc/apt that still seem set up for zesty